# Find and replace any possible instances of "StringVar1 == StringVar2" with "String1.equals(String2)" in a large Java codebase with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently attempting to find and replace any instances of `StringVar1 == StringVar2` in a large Eclipse project with `StringVar1.equals(StringVar2)`, so I've been looking for a way to find any possible matches to that without matching all `Var1 == Var2` statements in the code. I couldn't find a way to do this in Eclipse where I was able to specify the variables as only Strings in the search functions. I've also looked into trying custom refactoring scripts but was ultimately unsuccessful with them. Would anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: You can do this easily with Google's refaster. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43490333/3788176) which shows an example. (Disclaimer: I work for Google, other tools are available).

Comment: I didn't use Refaster, but on the installation page I was lead to the spotbugs plugin, which ended up finding this exact issue for me and fixing the problem. Thanks for helping find the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would install the PMD plugin which will find all string comparisons using == instead of .equals.

https://pmd.github.io/

https://pmd.github.io/latest/usage/integrations.html#Eclipse